# vim macro across screen windows

Tags: linux, vim, screen, vim-registers

I have recorded a vim macro in one screen window.
In same screen session, I have multiple windows.

How to make macro I recorded in 1st screen window across other screen windows / across screen sessions ?

Do we have to do something with vim registers for this ?

Answer (score 0):

- If the two screen windows show two separate Vim instances on the same machine

  - If Vim is built with clipboard support

    1. In the Vim instance where you recorded that macro, put the content of the macro's register into the clipboard register:

       ```
       " assuming you recorded your macro in register `a`
       :let @+ = @a
       ```
    2. In the other Vim instance, put the content of the clipboard register into a named named register:

       ```
       :let @a = @+
       ```
  - If Vim is not built with clipboard support

    Vim stores registers in a `.viminfo` file. You are theoretically allowed to write to and read from arbitrary `.viminfo` files but it can lead to unwanted loss of state in Vim. Read `:help viminfo-read-write` *very* carefully and proceed with caution.